# splits in map reduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, input-split, recordreader

I have an input file on which I need to customize the `RecordReader`. But, the problem here is, the data may get distributed across different input splits and different mapper may get the data which should be consumed by the first mapper.

For e.g. 
A B C D 
 $ E F

That '$' at the beginning signifies that, it is the continuation of the previous line.

Considering, the second split starts from $. Now, my first mapper won't know that there is something in continuation of first line.
Please, also note that there is a very good chance that I do not have any second line in my data at all. So, I won't be able to tell that there is something in continuation of my data until or unless I read the second line.

Please help me find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Is it possible to preprocess the data? I think that's the easiest way to achieve what you're asking.

Comment: I do not think so as for pre processing the data we need to parse it and the data being hudge .. its realy difficult to do that.